# Run a custom Maven goal without pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have developed a Maven plugin. How to run custom Maven goal from a directory that does not contain a `pom.xml`?

E.g. `mvn my.plugin:mygoal` <- no pom.xml in this dir.

Comment: For example, to create a `jar-with-dependencies` (as a one off). Or run a servlet in jetty (one of the most handy maven idioms I've seen).

Comment: in my case I want to use it to deploy an EAR on my wildfly, but this is an external ear

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the [`requiresProject`](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/annotations/Mojo.html#requiresProject%28%29) attribute of your MOJO to `false`:

> Flags this Mojo to run inside of a project.

By default, it is `true` meaning that this MOJO requires a project (hence a POM). As such, you should have in your plugin:

```java
@Mojo(requiresProject = false, ...)
public class MyMojo extends AbstractMojo  { ... }
```